# PHP echo showing on top of page instead of in being used in buttons

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I can't figure this out. I'm building this HTML link in WP using [Shortcoder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcoder/) (HTML below) and a self created plugin to create a shortcode (PHP below) and CSS to create the button (CSS below).

The problem is that the shortcode, [upo_url_shortlink] (php below) is showing up (echoed) on top of the page instead of being used by the link (&url). Everything else is in place. The short url used is generated by Short URL and the url that is echoed is the correct one. It is just not used by the button link...

Example page: http://www.behind-the-scenes.co.za/Ib0Lf

Can someone please see what I'm doing wrong?

```html
<span class="upo-share-buttons"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[types field="twitter-text" output="raw"][/types]&url=[upo_url_shortlink]&via=RenierDelport &hashtags=[types field="visitor-twitter-hashtags" output="raw"][/types]" target="_blank" title="Share [wpv-post-title] on Twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></span>
```

```html
// [upo_url_shortlink]
function upo_url_shortlink_function() {
 echo wp_get_shortlink();
}
add_shortcode('upo_url_shortlink', 'upo_url_shortlink_function');
```

```css
.upo-share-buttons {
 display: inline-block;
 border-right: 2px solid white;
 width: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 padding: 5px;
 position: relative;
 background-color:#ff0000;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,OffY=1,Color=#ff123852,Positive=true)";zoom:1;
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,OffY=1,Color=#ff123852,Positive=true);
 -moz-box-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow:0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,OffY=2,Color=#33000000,Positive=true)";
 filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=0,OffY=2,Color=#33000000,Positive=true);
}

.upo-share-buttons a:link, .upo-share-buttons a:visited {
 color: white !important;
}

.upo-share-buttons a:hover {
 color: #eeeaee !important
}
```

Comment: where do you add this button code in any page or script file like single.php  ?

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention it. The share button used to be called from a php template file, but I'm converting it to be called from WP Views Content Template. These templates are not to php friendly, so I only add shortcodes and HTML in them. The Content Template calls the shortcode made with Shortcoder (which contains the HTML and shortcodes mentioned first.

Comment: Given that `wp_get_shortlink()` returns the value rather than echoing it (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_shortlink), I'm guessing the culprit is the Shortcoder plugin.  What happens if you change  `echo wp_get_shortlink()` to `return wp_get_shortlink()` ?

Comment: McNab, that worked perfectly. You are such a star! Thanks. And thanks siddhesh too!

Comment: You cannot call the shortcode in template files. you have to call the shortcode at page content. They are invented for that purpose. In template file you can call function directly.

Comment: That is true siddhesh. When I was calling the short link from php I used wp_get_shortlink() directly. Upon converting it to a Views Content Template I had to make a [shortlink] from wp_get_shortlink(). Witch was, as pointed out by McNab the problem. Had to return it instead of echoeing it.

Comment: No problem - should have just answered it straight away, I see someone else has grabbed it and created an answer. That'll teach me to go out to lunch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be returning your output not echoing it. try changing your shortcode to...

```
function upo_url_shortlink_function() {
    return wp_get_shortlink();
}
add_shortcode('upo_url_shortlink', 'upo_url_shortlink_function');
```

Hope that helps

Dan